# How can I align icons with their titles?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

As you can see from this screenshot, My icons aren't aligned with their titles. They are written as two unordered lists. The only solution I have right now is to give individual `margin-left` to each of the icons, but I'm hoping there is a better way to do it. Any help would be very much appreciated.[image: Screenshot]

HTML:

```
<!-- Skills -->
<section id="skills">
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><i class="icon-prog-java"></i></li>
    <li><i class="icon-prog-js02"></i></li>
    <li><i class="icon-html5-02"></i></li>
    <li><i class="icon-css3-02"></i></li>
    <li><i class="icon-vc-git"></i></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Java</li>
    <li>JavaScript</li>
    <li>HTML / XML</li>
    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>Git</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#skills li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 40px;
}
```

Comment: How about including the icons along with each text list item?  (e.g. `<li><i class="icon-prog-java"></i>Java</li>`)

Comment: That puts the icons right next to the word. I was hoping to get them on top of each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate the icons with each of the text items.  Then, make the icons be on a separate line by making them block elements.  Also, each list item needs to be `inline-block` instead of `inline`:

```css
#skills li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.skill-list i {
  display: block;
  /* add margins here to adjust icons */
}
```

```html
<!-- Skills -->
<section id="skills">
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <ul class="skill-list">
    <li><i class="icon-prog-java"></i>Java</li>
    <li><i class="icon-prog-js02"></i>JavaScript</li>
    <li><i class="icon-html5-02"></i>HTML / XML</li>
    <li><i class="icon-css3-02"></i>CSS</li>
    <li><i class="icon-vc-git"></i>Git</li>
  </ul>
</section>

<!-- Pictonic library, ignore this -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/thedrick/tylerhedrick.me@master/resources/pictonic/css/pictonic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also sorry for not linking to the pictonic css, props for figuring it out yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

@MrFusion has better answer. Please prefer that method.

But if you don't want icons and texts to be in same `ul` try defining fixed width for `li`s.

```
#skills li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were to create this I would have one list item grouping. Each of the

would have the img tag for the icon along with an  tag or any other block level element. This allows me to scope my CSS to the

’s and all of them would be affected by my styles. It’s like creating  individual uniform boxes for my icons and titles. The method that you are using now makes it complicated. If things change in the future you will have two areas to keep an eye on.

If you wish to continue down this road though you could try giving the #skills li a fixed width and they should all line up.